# Opposite of materialistic?

Tags: antonyms

I'm looking for a word to describe a person who doesn't care about the fundamental things in their life, a person who cares about the meaningful activities such as charity or similar things.

Comment: Of course, the opposite of materialistic might be 'un-materialistic', but if you wanted to add in 'meaningful activities', the word "virtuous" serves you well -- as I believe that 'virtue' is defined by the standards of the day ... and perhaps it's new overtones would have less to do with the overtones we attribute to "morally upright" *conforming to moral and ethical principles; morally excellent; upright:* http://www.dictionary.com/browse/virtuous

Comment: How interesting that you say 'a person who doesn't care about the fundamental things in their life'. It seems to me that the fundamental things in life ARE the meaningful activities, charity work, etc. Or did you mean the person has no interest in their material things/objects? Your title suggests it's exactly that, but I wonder if your question might be rephrased to reflect the fact that it's not 'fundamental things' the person isn't interested in - it's the acquisition of objects per se that is of no interest to them.

Comment: If you literally mean the opposite of materialistic then: abstemious, thrifty, frugal. But if you mean what I think you mean based on the rest of your question then I think 3kstc gave the best answer: Altruistic or Ascetic.

Answer (score 5):

**Altruistic** is defined by [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/altruistic) as:

> *unselfishly concerned for or devoted to the welfare of others*

---

**Ascetic** is defined by [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ascetic) as:

> *a person who leads an austerely simple life, especially one who abstains from the normal pleasures of life or denies himself or herself material satisfaction.*

Answer (score 0):

**spartan**

> adjective
>   [(M-W)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Spartan) 2 a : marked by strict self-discipline or self-denial
>   *a Spartan athlete*
>
> [(M-W)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Spartan) 2 b : marked by simplicity, frugality, or avoidance of luxury and comfort
>   *a Spartan room*
>
> ([dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/spartan)) 2. suggestive of the ancient Spartans; sternly disciplined and rigorously simple, frugal, or austere.

**austere**

> adjective
>   ([dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/austere)) 2. rigorously self-disciplined and severely moral; ascetic; abstinent:
>   *the austere quality of life in the convent.*
>
> ([dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/austere)) 4. without excess, luxury, or ease; simple; limited; severe:
>   *an austere life.*

Answer (score 0):

Stoic

1. A disciple of the philosopher Zeno; one of a Greek sect
   which held that men should be free from passion, unmoved
   by joy or grief, and should submit without complaint to
   unavoidable necessity, by which all things are governed.
   [1913 Webster]

Your question is ambiguous though - because 'the fundamental things in life' are relative to the observer. So, a stoic would define those 'fundamental things' differently than you might.

Since virtues and vices in stoicism are ultimately up to the individual to define - virtue for one person may be vice for another. These values aren't dependent on the values defined by the larger society but they aren't completely detached from them either. So, given that the 'fundamental things in life' is defined by the society in which one lives, the stoic is able to separate their own definition of virtue and vice from that definition.